# How to reorder input billing address in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, billing-address

I want move this input to this, it is suffix input. I use this code but it not work in billing address. I created module and followed https://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend/reorder-input-fields-shipping-billing-step-magento-2/ but it not work for me.

Please help me.

My code in checkout_index_index of my theme

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="prefix" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="suffix" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Try this https://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend/reorder-input-fields-shipping-billing-step-magento-2/

Comment: thanks for answer, i tryed, it not woking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above code is for the Shipping address. For the billing address, we had to add a check depending on the checkout configuration in admin about where to display the billing address, on the payment method or payment page, as then the array keys are different.

So the shipping address fields will be shown like below in checkout.

Check detailed information on https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/change-order-of-address-fields-in-checkout-magento-2/

Comment: if i want reorder suffix name input, can i change telephone -> suffix ?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, you can try it.

Comment: It work for me, thank you very much.

Comment: Good to hear... You're welcome.